# Is this statement an axiom "The probability that a continuous variable exactly equals to a given value is zero"?

Tags: probability, reference-request

This statement "the probability that a continuous variable exactly equals to a given value is zero" is commonly used.

is this an axiom, a property of continuous variable, a rule of integration or a conclusion of measure theory?

please provide a citation of a textbook or formally publication.

the [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_indifference#Application_to_continuous_variables) itself some answer linked is being tagged "unclear sources"

Comment: @JMoravitz please provide a citation of a textbook or formally publication.

the wiki itself your answer linked is being tagged "unclear sources"

Comment: @JMoravitz I am not asking for an explanation. I am asking for a solid sources.

Comment: Why are you shouting?

Comment: It is a property of a continuous random variable. If it is true for every value then the random variable is by definition a continuous random variable.

Comment: It can be proven by anybody.  It doesn't need a clear original source since it is such a basic application of fundamentals.  Do we need a cited source when talking about the color of the sky?  If you want to cite something, then cite the linked answer.

Comment: @saulspatz because someone is trying to close my question without considering what I am actually asking.

Comment: Someone has voted to close your question as a duplicate.  If you think that the answers given to that question don't answer yours, please explain why not.  How is your question different?  You should this in the body of the question, not the comments.

Comment: @saulspatz I've done that, although obviously JMoravitz doesn't buy that.

Comment: Any decent textbook of probability theory should contain a definition of "continuous random variable" (if it doesn't, I wouldn't call it decent).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A random variable $X$ is by definition a *continuous* random variable if and only if $P(X=x)=0$ for every $x\in\mathbb R$.

Comment: If you define a *continuous* r.v. so, then you need to define *absolutely continuous* r.v., and then it turns out that *absolutely continuous r.v.* is all that the probability theory really needs; I prefer to reserve the term *continuous r.v.* for a random variable having probability density.

Comment: @kludg Well, so be it. For me nothing is wrong with the term "absolutely continuous" for a random variable that has a probability density. IMHV it is narrow-minded to say that then it turns out that absolutely continuous is all that probability theory really needs.

Answer (score 0):

This [washington handout](https://www.stat.washington.edu/~nehemyl/files/UW_MATH-STAT395_continuous-rrv.pdf) gives

> Property 1.1. If X is a continuous rrv, then
>   For all $a\in\mathbb R, \ \mathbb P(X = a) = 0$